# Strings of two letters and fixed length

Tags: python, string

I'm wondering how to generate a list of all possible two-letter strings of length 10 in Python. For example, the list would go:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaba
aaaaaaaabb
...
...
...
bbbbbbbbab
bbbbbbbbba
bbbbbbbbbb
```

Also, I'm aware of how naive my question might be; I'm still in the learning process.

Comment: one simple approach (beside using existing python tools such as itertools) is too consider those as binary numbers: 1 for b, 0 for a. Then each string becomes the representation of a number, and to get all the strings, you only have to go through all the numbers.

Comment: The leading zeroes would be difficult to account for with your suggestion.

Comment: @EdwardJiang: Not really; Python has `str.zfill` and `str.rjust` to pad out a `str` to a given width on the left, or you can use `format`/`str.format` to achieve a similar effect as a single operation (instead of converting to `str`, then padding as separate steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count from `0` to `2**10-1`, convert those numbers using `bin` and replace 0/1 with a/b. Just pad the left side with 0's to the right length.

Comment: Thanks @Alfe! Silly typo.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import product

prod = [''.join(p) for p in product('ab', repeat=10)]
```

or if you just want to print it like in your example:

```
from itertools import product

for p in product('ab', repeat=10):
    print(''.join(p))
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for `itertools.product`

Answer (score 0):

```
def s(d):
  if d:
    for c in 'ab':
      for rest in s(d-1):
        yield c + rest
  else:
    yield ''

print list(s(10))
```

or

```
def x(d):
  return ([ 'a' + q for q in x(d-1) ] +
          [ 'b' + q for q in x(d-1) ]) if d else [ '' ]

print x(10)
```