# Create a sequence of two letters of length 10 using Linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have been trying to create a sequence of two letters based on a length. I know a similar question has been asked in python [Strings of two letters and fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36586442/5274722) but it differs slightly.

[Edit]

Example
abababababa is a string sequence of a , b and fixed length 11

I came up with this quick solution but I feel there is a much smarter way to do this. The fixed length can be even or odd number. For instance,

```
string b =String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Concat("a", "b"), 11));
Console.WriteLine(b.Substring(0,11));
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is the string always supposed to just be the two letters alternating? Is the output length always an even number, so that both letters always appear the same number of times? Why can't you just repeat your substring (a single pair of letters) 5 times instead of 10? Does this really have to be LINQ?

Comment: No sometimes the output length is an odd number. Good Spot on the 5 times ish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" would probably be `char[]` or `StringBuilder` with a `for` loop, 
but here are few shorter ways:

```
string a = new string('a', 11).Replace("aa", "ab");

string b = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => "ab"[i & 1]));

string c = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, "ab", ((11 + 1) / 2)).ToString(0, 11);
```

Answer (score 2):

I still am not 100% sure I understand what you're asking. However, based on what you've written so far, I'd think this would do what you want:

```
string Repeat(string input, int length)
{
    return new string(
        Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(i => input[i % length]).ToArray());
}
```

Called like:

```
string result = Repeat("ab", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want? im confused.

`string b = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Concat("a", "b"), 5));`

Comment: This doesn't work when the fixed length is not an even number